# Как сохранить вывод любой команды в файл и сразу же увидеть его в терминале?

Tags: bash, shell, powershell

Как после долгого ожидания вывода сохранить то что увидел в файл?

Допустим по команде:

```
git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list --all)
```

Я понимаю что было бы предусмотрительно наличие `> log.txt` в конце, хочется сразу сохранять что увидел?

Все сам разобрался, суть в следующем если допустим набрать просто `git log`, появится диалог просмотра со значком `:`. Этот экран можно двигать вверх вниз там, а вот если нажать кнопку `s` то появится диалог ввода имени файла, остается набрать допустим `log.txt` и весь вывод будет сохранен в этот файл

Comment: Вам хочется и видеть и сохранять одновременно?

Comment: Мне надо сохранить увиденное т.к. данная операция выполняется очень долго если коммитов много

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/418896

Answer (score 5):

Чтобы увидеть вывод и сохранить его одновременно есть [специальная команда **tee**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee), пример:

```
command | tee log.txt
```

[image: cхема, объясняющая работу команды tee]
Иллюстрация: [Wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee#/media/File:Tee.svg), [GFDL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html).

Comment: Знаю я эту команду, время от времени пользуюсь, однако я не могу постоянно ее помнить и вставлять где надо и ненадо

Мне надо сохранить увиденное т.к. данная операция выполняется очень долго если коммитов много

Comment: большинство терминалов поддерживают логированние. Настройте себе и не будете забывать. Но думаю, поможет просто увеличить буфер для терминала - тогда будет доступна прокрутка.

Answer (score 0):

Если не для одной команды, а для "сеанса", то я пользуюсь командой `script`
(весь протокол работы будет в файле ./typescript, а вообще, посмотрите `man script`).